# Sequelize - Get values in descending order

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to connect to mysql database. 
I've 2 tables ApplicationVersion and Provider in my Database. Both the tables are associated. ApplicationVersion has Provider 'uuid' as the foreign key.

In my Provider table, I've a column called `weight`. This weight field has integer values. I want to display elements in descending order. so I've used this line  `order: [Sequelize.col('weight'), 'DESC'],` in my function but it doesn't work. The function works well if i remove the order from it.

Here's the function:

```
function getactiveProvidersList(user, callback) {
        Provider.findAll({where: {enabled: 1},
            include: [{
                    model: ApplicationVersion,
                    where: {'active': true},
                }],
                order: [Sequelize.col('weight'), 'DESC'],
            }).then(function(providers) {
                 callback(providers);
                });
    }
```

Could you please tell me the right way of doing it and also where i'm messing this up.

Any suggestion is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
function getactiveProvidersList(user, callback) {
            Provider.findAll({where: {enabled: 1},
                include: [{
                        model: ApplicationVersion,
                        where: {'active': true},
                    }],
                    order: ['weight','DESC'],
                }).then(function(providers) {
                     callback(providers);
                    });
        }
```

there are more suggestions on this here as well at the bottom of the page

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Comment: Tried both of them but they don't work. It says `Provider.Literal` is not a  function and `Provider.fn` is not a function

Comment: `order: [ ['weight', 'DESC'],],` This worked for me. Thanks @Legman

Comment: I tried it doesnt work order: [ ['weight', 'DESC'],], instead